# Notepad++ and Cygwin

Tags: ubuntu, notepad++, cygwin

I'm connecting to an Ubuntu server hosted by AWS, using Cygwin to connect through my Windows box.  Does anyone know of a way I can configure it so that I type a command at the Ubuntu prompt to edit a file?  IOW, at the unix prompt I'd like to type something like "n_edit [filename]" and the file would open up in Notepad++ in Windows.  Is that possible?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe Just use winscp

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write, @DavidDai.  WinSCP is a great program, isn't it?  I actually use it and like it a lot.  I'm just in the command line so much that I was looking for a way to save a step.

Comment: I’m afraid your question doesn’t make much sense and it could be very difficult to do. Why not take the time to learn vim or Emacs?